# How can I get a total for space used by a group of subdirectories

Tags: filesystems, disk-usage

My file system is set up like:

```
/ftp/data/ProductGroup*/ProductType*/Year*/Day*/ActualProductFile*
```

("*"denotes directory names that change)

I'd like to find out how much space is being used for 2011 products.  Something like

```
du -ks /ftp/data/*/*/2011
```

However, I need the sum of all these directories - there are hundreds of them and I don't want to have to add them all up (too error prone!)

Would anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: and `du`'s `-c` option isn't what you are looking for?

Comment: @llua, not all `du` implementations support the `-c` option as that's not a standard option.

Comment: Ah, never knew that^

Answer (score 1):

Simply pipe the results from `du` into something that will perform the addition for you:

```
du -ks /ftp/data/*/*/2011 |
    sed -e 's/\(^[0-9]*\).*$/\1 +/' -e '1s/^/0 /' -e '$s/$/ p/' | dc
```

Comment: I think using awk to sum the column would be more elegant some thing like  `du -ks /ftp/data/*/*/211 | awk '{ n+=$1; }; END { print n; }'`

Comment: Sure, that looks less cryptic than mine :-)